# I want to play wav file stored in external directory but I am not able to create MediaPlayer instance

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, media-player

I am writing a small app that creates wav files using a microphone. I am using AudioRecord class do get raw data and then I am saving it in wav format in external storage. The problem is I can not create MediaPlayer instance to saved wav files. I am able to open the selected file and I have got the permissions to read it. Wav files are saved correctly (at least I guess so because I can play then on computer). I would be grateful for any help :)

What I have got so far:

```
@Override
public void onRecordingClick(int position) {
    if (player == null) {
        String path = wavFilepathList.get(position);
        File audioFile = new File(path);

        Log.d("audioFileLog", "File exists: " + audioFile.exists() + ", can read: " + audioFile.canRead());

        player = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            player.setDataSource(path);
            Log.d("audioFileLog", "Data Source Changed");
            player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            Log.d("audioFileLog", "Listener Set, before prepare method");
            player.prepareAsync();
            Log.d("audioFileLog", "after prepare method");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("audioFileLog", "IOException when setting data source");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.start();
    Log.d("audioFileLog", "after played method");
}
```

Logcat:

```
D/audioFileLog: File exists: true, can read: true
E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
D/audioFileLog: Data Source Changed
D/audioFileLog: Listener Set, before prepare method
D/audioFileLog: after prepare method
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
```

Older experiments:
1)

```
public void onRecordingClick(int position) {
    if (player == null) {

        File selectedFile = new File(wavFilepathList.get(position));

        Log.d("Main", "voice exists : " + selectedFile.exists() +
                ", can read : " + selectedFile.canRead());
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.fromFile(selectedFile));
    }
    player.start();
} // on recording clicked
```

Logcat:

```
D/Main: voice exists : true, can read : true  
E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails  
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0  
E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails  
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0  
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)  
D/MediaPlayer: create failed:
```

2)

```
@Override
public void onRecordingClick(int position) {
    if (player == null) {

        player= new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            player.setDataSource(wavFilepathList.get(position));

            player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            player.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} // on recording clicked

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    player.start();
}
```

Logcat:

```
E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file patch was incorrect hence the problem...

Comment: It would be better if you explained how correct it. One-liners cannot be recommendable as answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the mediaPlayer using the following way:

```
    try{
        File audioFile = new File("The File's Path");     //  audio.wav path
        if(audioFile.exists()){    
            Log.d("audioFileLog", "Found the file");
            MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
            mp.setDataSource('audioFile.getPath());
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        }else{
            Log.d("audioFileLog", "Did not find the file");
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        Log.d("audioFileLog", ex.toString());
    }
```

and then use:

```
mp.stop();
mp.release();
```

when you have finished.

Comment: Perhaps you made some mistake before, because i am using the above code in 2 different apps and it has not failed me once! ;)  Give it one more try! :)

Comment: I have edited a question with yours solution. Got erros as well :( May you take a look? Maybe I am making some stupid mistake

Comment: See my updated version to also check if you find the file or not before trying to play it.

Comment: When I am using prepare() method it Logs an Error aboute state 0 so I have changed it to work asynchronous. Anyway still no sund from my speaker :(

Comment: Change your `catch (IOException e)` to `catch (Exception e)`

Comment: It does not raise any exception, it do not even stop the application. The errors I am showing are logs from Logcat. It just do not play anything. When I copied file from external storage and added it to raw directory in application and then created "player" variable by MediaRecorder.create(context, R.raw.filename) it played that file. The problem is I can not save recorded file in raw directory, can I?

Comment: Try something else first. After you get your file using `File audioFile = new File(path);` check you file's size using `audioFile.length();` to make sure this file is actually the real file you are looking for.

Comment: it is correct file for sure, I tested if can delete it in that method and I can. Now I am getting **java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1"**, may it be caused because files are in wav format?

Comment: No, wav format is fine. I use mediaplayer to play both mp3 and wav files with no problem.